# Not able to install packages in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have pycharm community edition(latest stable build) installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I am not able to install packages via pycharm, was able to install them before. I can install the packages  via pip, but would like to solve this issue.

Below is the Screenshot of the problem

[image]

Have googled for this issue, but could not find any fix, I have a windows machine and it does not face the same issue.

Comment: What is the version of PyCharm? Apparently there was a bug but it seems to be fixed. Check [this link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20081) to see if your version is one of the affected ones and upgrade if necessary.

Comment: @HamiTorun I am using the updated version of pycharm

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have got a solution, i reffered to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20081#u=1468410176856.

Here they have tried to add https://pypi.python.org/pypi as a repository.

To add it as a repository,

```
1.) Go to Settings
2.) Project interpreter
3.) Click the + sign on top right edge
4.) Go to manage repositories, 
5.) Press the + Sign, then add https://pypi.python.org/pypi
6.) Press Ok
```

Now all the packages should load.

Thanks Hami Torun & Simon, I was able to solve it by luck.

Comment: List is still empty for me - (pycharm 5.0.5)

Comment: @Logic1 Can you tell me what version does it show in Help -> About (in pycharm)

Comment: when I add pypi, it automatically removes it and replaces it with simple. no success!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. It happened suddenly, day ago I was able to perform pip or install packages but on the next day error appeared. However this helped (I used version PyCharm Community Edition 2018):

Go to Settings -> Project Interpreter -> click green "+" icon (on right) -> Manage Repositories (on bottom) -> delete https://pypi.python.org/simple -> add https://pypi.python.org/pypi
then click Ok. Repo will be back again as /simple, but don't worry, error should disappear and you should be able to install packages again.

Comment: I tried this but with no luck. it turns out pip was the culprit. pip had somehow updated itself from 9.0.1 to 10. , and this pip 10 was wreaking havoc

Comment: @kRazzyR 
**DO NOT USE** pip 10 in PyCharm! It's still bugged, get back pip to 9, in Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Repository, choose pip and then choose older version. Source: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/04/pycharm-hotfix-for-pip-10-0-and-ipython-6-3-0-compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because of low space in my pc. After I free up space the problem solved. Pycharm did not say anything about this problem. It just shows that "the package installed successfully", but actually package was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem.
My project was created by PyCharm, with venv.
The package I was installing via manager (Ctrl+Alt+S), was showing in the list, but it wasn't being recognized or imported.

I believe the error happened because I tried to install it before, using `pip install` into IDE's own terminal. Also pip version in the manager was a beta version, then I changed it to a stable version.

Had to start a new project in a new folder.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I had to update my `pip` version from the PyCharm terminal:

`pip install --upgrade pip`