# Available packages empty in Pycharm with Anaconda interpretter

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda in my Windows 7 64 bit with Python 2.7.13.

I set up the interpretter in my Python by locating the python.exe within the anaconda installation directory.

I can run programmes. However, I can not install additional packages using the package installer of Pycharm.
[image]

I have looked at online guides, but nothing helpful so far. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I added the link https://pypi.python.org/simple using the Manager Repositories button.
[image]

However, it does not work

Comment: I'm with the very same problem right now. Did you get to solve it?

Comment: I had the same situation; however, installing all the packages manually via the terminal at the bottom of the pycharm window (ie `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib`) worked for me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Pycharm has updated and this question has been resolved

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was a known issue with Pycharm in some release(s) from a few years ago. As the close initiator has stated Pycharm has had a number of version updates since this post was raised and this particular issue was resolved so the post is probably no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click `Manage Repositories`

Does anything show up there? I'm guessing you don't have anything. I have `https://pypi.python.org/simple`. So..

2. `Click '+' symbol`
3. Fill in `https://pypi.python.org/simple`
4. `Click OK`
5. `Click refresh wheel on the frame you screenshot`

Did that work?

Comment: Did you mean the 'Manage repositories' button?

Comment: yes, on the gui window that you have in your question

Comment: did you click the refresh button on that same gui window afterwards?

Comment: Yes, many times. Could it be that the pip is located elsewhere in anaconda? I found it under the scripts folder in anaconda

Comment: What is your `Project Interpreter` pointing to? `Settings | Project | Project Interpreter `

Comment: You shouldn't be pointing to a `pip` file. You should be pointing to a `python.exe`. For instance, my `python.exe` is located at `C:\Users\nanotek\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe`, and this is what my `Project Interpreter` points to (for my anaconda area). However, I'm not an `Anaconda` expert so I don't know if this is common. My `2.7` path is `C:\Python27\python.exe` which seems much more "normal"

Comment: That is exactly what I did. When I use the official installation, the package installer in pycharm works fine. However, when I point to anaconda's python interpretter, the package installer fails

Comment: Let me also add, initially the pip was not found in the environmental variables.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060353/not-able-to-install-packages-in-pycharm) and [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20081#u=1468410176856) look to be the same issue and it seems adding the repository helped. If that doesn't work for you, my next thought would be something setup related, and maybe I would try re-installing anaconda, or creating a new project, or maybe even re-installing PyCharm. Beyond that I don't think there's anything else I can suggest that would help.

Comment: You saved my life!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKTNWI0eYJ4

Comment: Manage Repository button is not present on Available Package Dialog.  I am using PyCharm 2022.1.2 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-221.5787.24, built on May 31, 2022

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution to this is that install your needed package into **Anaconda Prompt**(Run anaconda prompt in administrator mode.) using pip command then that package will automatically be reflected into pycharm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which specific step. Just follow the steps below:

1. Reinstall your anaconda
2. Be sure to open your anaconda once before connecting it with Pycharm
3. When "scanning" shows up, it works.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Change the project interpreter from the drop down menu to your default python interpreter, then the packages should appear.