# i can't install any librery files in pyCharm jetBrains, can't understant the real reason

Tags: python

When i go for downloading libraries its shows nothing, no libraries. No liraries to download .plz help me out .

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install packages in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060353/not-able-to-install-packages-in-pycharm)

Comment: Why is this upvoted? A quick search on this would have shown there is a duplicate question on SO and OP didn't even tell if he tried at least anything to make it work.

Comment: thanks , but i have already tried that way couldn't solve the problem .