# Pycharm Package Install Problems

Tags: python, pycharm, installation, package

I am having problems installing packages in Pycharm. I have the most recent version of Pycharm and Python downloaded.

I tried the multiple solutions here:

[Not able to install packages in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060353/not-able-to-install-packages-in-pycharm)

but none worked

[image: screenshot]

I then tried to change the repository like the above link suggests but am getting the error message 'Error updating package list: connect timed out'

After I looked at changing my version of pip from 10 to 9.0.1 but I am unable to since I cannot access a repository. I cannot even specify the version through Pycharm.

Would appreciate the help, thanks.

Comment: @Prateek Should just try uninstalling pycharm? The repository change trick does not work for me. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install packages in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060353/not-able-to-install-packages-in-pycharm)

Comment: Try both solutions from the mentioned question.