# Can't import Twilio package on Pycharm

Tags: twilio

In the last couple of days I've been working with Twilio package. Didn't have any kind of problem until today when I tried to import it for a new project (using PyCharm) and appears this message

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What channels were listed? The [Twilio Python library is hosted on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/twilio/), is that where PyCharm is looking for it? Was the package repository temporarily down and does it work to install things now?

Comment: No completely. I still can't import the module.

Comment: Do any of the answers here help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060353/not-able-to-install-packages-in-pycharm?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Anaconda Navigator, launch the CMD.exe Prompt. Type "pip install twilio" and run. That solved it for me.